# ¿Por que a libreria de Jquery "Autocomplete" no me sugiere los resultados?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

muchísimas gracias por sus aportes y ayudas, el día de hoy me encuentro con otro problema acerca de la librería de Jquery de Autocomplete, en su funcionamiento normal debería de arrojarme las sugerencias de los resultados según que caracter se encuentre en la casilla de texto, me explico:

Si yo coloco la letra "a" debería de arrojarme todos los resultados que se asocian a esa letra, pero en este caso esto no sucede si no que me trae todos los resultados pero son filtrar el caracter inicial.

Este sistema de autocompletado para lo que lo utilizo es para cuando yo llene un input se llenen otros automáticamente, hasta aquí todo bien, pero no realiza las sugerencias.

El script que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#nombres").autocomplete({
            source: "buscarempleado.php",
            minLength: 2
        });

        $("#nombres").focusout(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'empleado.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    nombres: $('#nombres').val()
                }
            }).done(function(respuesta) {
                $("#cedula").val(respuesta.cedula);
                $("#cargo").val(respuesta.cargo);
                $("#proceso").val(respuesta.proceso);
                $("#nucleo").val(respuesta.nucleo);
                $("#eps").val(respuesta.eps);
            });
        });
    });
```

Estos datos son traídos desde la base de datos que tengo, y esa información del script es la siguiente:

```
<?php
$matricula = $_GET['term'];
include ("conn.php");
  
$consulta = "SELECT nombres FROM clientes WHERE nombres LIKE '%$nombres%'";
  
$result = $conn->query($consulta);
  
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($fila = $result->fetch_array()){
        $nombress[] = $fila['nombres'];
    }
echo json_encode($nombress);
}
?>
```

Esa consulta anterior es la que me permite llamar a los nombres de unos empleados en especifico y para traer su información adicional uso la siguiente consulta:

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['term'])){
//Conectando a la base de datos
$con = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'mysql', 'ebd');
$con->set_charset("utf8");
$term = $con->real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
$return_arr = array();

if ($query = $con->query("SELECT id, nombres, cedula, cargo, proceso, nucleo, eps FROM clientes WHERE nombres LIKE '%$term%' LIMIT 0 ,50
 ")) {
    while ($obj = $query->fetch_object()) {
        $row_array['id']=$obj->id;
        $row_array['cedula']=$obj->cedula;
        $row_array['cargo'] = $obj->cargo;
        $row_array['proceso'] = $obj->proceso;
        $row_array['nucleo'] = $obj->nucleo;
        $row_array['eps'] = $obj->eps;
        array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
    }

    $query->close();
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
?>
```

Ahora, cuando coloco un nombre en especifico pasa lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En total son 215 empleados y me los arroja en ese UI de Jquery, el cual no debería ser así, si no que cuando coloque dicho nombre solo me muestre ese nombre.

Esto se está utilizando para un sistema web con Bootstrap, PHP Y MySQLi pero en este caso se me ha presentado este problema, con respecto a las versiones del Jquery estoy utilizando las últimas versiones, así que no se si se trata de alguna especie de Bug o quizás me falte algo en el código, cualquier ayuda es bienvenida y nuevamente a todos muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Primero: tenes configurado el autocomplete `minLength: 2`, es decir, cuando tengas dos caracteres, recién va a proceder a buscar. Segundo: en `buscarempleado.php` guardas el texto buscando en la variable `$matricula` pero no la usas para buscar los clientes... diría que deberías cambiarla a  `$nombres`

Comment: Ay dios mio, que vergüenza me acabo de percatar de ese problema, muchísimas gracias :D.